How to create selector with parameters like in NGRX signalStore like `createSelector` in NGXS?
I'm refactoring the code and I started to moving code to the signalStore, but I was stuck while creating custom selector with some property to make it like signal computed value.
NGXS Code:
interface Permission { 
   name: string;
}

interface UserStateModel {
   permissions: Permission[];
}

const DEFAULT_STATE: UserStateModel= {  
    permissions: []
};

@State<UserStateModel>({
    name: 'user_state',
    defaults: DEFAULT_STATE,
})
@Injectable()
export class UserState {
    @Selector()
    static permissions(state: UserStateModel): Permission[] {
        return state.permissions;
    }

    static permission(spermissionName: string) {
       return createSelector(
           [UserState.permissions], 
           (permissions) => permissions.find(x => x.name === permissionName)
        })

     }
}

As you can see, I can use UserState.permission('myPermissionName') and do any action if this position change.
export type UserStoreModel = {
    permissions: Permission[;
};

const DEFAULT_STATE: UserStoreModel = {
    permissions: [],
};

export const UserStore = signalStore(
    withState(DEFAULT_STATE),
    withComputed(store => {
        return {
            permissions: computed(() => store.permissions() ?? []),
        };
    }),
);

It should be a method which return Signals? Maybe there is something like createSelector which I can use here with Signals?
Thanks for help.
I did a research but I can't find any valid solution for this.
I'm expecting I will be able to make selector with Signals using ngrx signalStore.
Example usage of this:
/// My view

const hasAccessPermissions = computed(() => {
   const result = this.userStore.hasAccess('MyPermission');   //<--- this should be reactive
   return result;
});

private readonly userStore = inject(UserStore);


You don't need that computed signal for the permissions.  The
SignalStore provides signals for all the properties on your state
automagically, so you can just reference userStore.permissions
without needing to add that computed item.
Because userStore.permissions is a signal, you can just create the
computed "selector" in your component...
userStore = inject(UserStore);
hasAccess = computed(() => {
    return userStore.permissions()
             .findIndex(p => p.name == 'MyPermission') >= 0;
});

hasAccess() will be responsive to changes in the store's permissions array. If you find you are using this pattern all over the place, you could add a factory method to your store..
withMethods((store) => ({
    hasPermission: (name: string): Signal<boolean> => computed(() => {
        return store.permissions()
             .findIndex(p => p.name == name) >= 0;
    })
}))

then in any component you can use
userStore = inject(UserStore);
canJump = userStore.hasPermission('JumpPermission');
canDance = userStore.hasPermission('DancePermission');

now canJump and canDance are computed signals you can use.  Or lets say you had a component where the user can pick what permission to check and that is itself a signal, but you don't want to add it as a permanent part of the state.. refactor the hasPermission method...
withMethods((store) => ({
    hasPermission: (name: Signal<string>): Signal<boolean> => computed(() => {
        return store.permissions()
             .findIndex(p => p.name == name()) >= 0;
    })
}))

and then in the consuming component you could have
// this signal is set whenever the user picks a new permission
// in a dropdown
selectedPermission = signal('DefaultPermission');

userStore = inject(UserStore);
hasPermission = userStore.hasPermission(selectedPermission);

now hasPermission is a computed signal that is responsive to both the list of permissions in the store as well as the selectedPermission that is being checked.
